# How to extract the cells used in a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to know which cells are engaged with formula in VBA.

For example, suppose `E12` has this formula `=AVERAGE(D12:D17)` and I want extract the list of cells `D12...D17` from this cell, how can I achieve that?

```
Dim fCell Az Range
Set fCell = Range("E12")
' know how to extract list
```

Comment: Look into `Range.Dependents`

Comment: Just FYI you can use `CTRL+]` and `CTRL+[` on a cell, and it'll take you to either a formula that the cell is referenced in, or if it's a formula it'll take you to the ranges used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DirectPrecedents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.directprecedents) property. Try something like:

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("E12").DirectPrecedents
    Debug.Print r.Address(False, False) & " = " & r.Value
Next
```

**Output:**

```
D12 = 5
D13 = 10
D14 = 15
D15 = 14
D16 = 9
D17 = 20
```